# Powershell Script to search specific OU in AD and find disabled users that is member of a group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, memberof

I'm trying to write a script to find disabled users that is member of one or more groups in a specific OU in AD. It will then remove all the groups for all the disabled users. I found this script which removes all groups from users in a csv file, but as i'm looking to run this as a scheduled task I prefer not to process users that already had their groups removed without having to move them to a different OU.

```
Import-Csv $csvFile | ForEach-Object {
    # Disable the account
    Disable-ADAccount -Identity $_.samAccountName
    # Retrieve the user object and MemberOf property
    $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.samAccountName -Properties MemberOf
    # Remove all group memberships (will leave Domain Users as this is NOT in the MemberOf property returned by Get-ADUser)
    foreach ($group in ($user | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf))
    {
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to filter out the users with more then one group? 
I'm using this script to export disabled users that has not logged on for 60 days:

```
Get-QADUser -searchRoot $OuDomain -searchScope OneLevel -InactiveFor 61 -NotLoggedOnFor 61 -disabled -sizelimit 0
```

Thx

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place? Accounts are automatically removed from all groups when they're deleted. For disabled accounts you normally want to leave group memberships intact, in case you have to re-enable them for some reason.

Comment: We do not delete user accounts as we have reference to this account in our document management system, also they are managed by FIM and our HR system. If a user should rejoin the company, we want to him/her to keep their old username but start with a clean slate in regards to access to systems etc. As of now there is no good way to have FIM handle this task, as it needs to be run for users that has been disabled for 60 days.

Comment: Doubt we will change policy but there is nothing to stop you from creating a new user with the same name (You could record that). Way it stands you risk a resource out there that the "previous" user had access to. That assumes you assign resources to the user instead of the group. If you do assign to groups then again there is not reason to keep the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have filter by ou part down which is good. You have some thoughts in the beginning of you post but the only actual question is *how to filter out the users with more then one group*. Not sure if that is a typo or not but I read that as checking the count of groups a user has. A more realistic interpretation of that is filter users that could have at least one of a list of groups. I'm going to cover both.

**The Count**

I'm sure this is not what you want but just want to cover the base. The following would also work in a `Where-Object` clause

```
If((get-aduser $user -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf.Count -gt 0){Process...}
```

**Multiple Groups**

I'm sure this was your intention. Locate users that could contain one of serveral groups. This is best handled with regex.

```
$groupsFilter = "citrix_GateKeeper","barracuda_spam_alerts"
$groupsFilter = "($($groupsFilter -join '|'))"
# $groupsFilter in this example is: (citrix_GateKeeper|barracuda_spam_alerts)

If(((Get-ADUser $user -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf) -match $groupsFilter){Process....}
```

Create a regex match string based on a string array of multiple groups. If $user is a member of either of those groups then true would be returned.

If nothing here is of any use to you then I would suggest making your question clearer. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I was actually looking for something similar to your first suggestion, sorry for not being clearer. I figured it out thx to your example

    Get-QADUser -searchRoot $OuDomain -Properties memberOf|Where-Object {$_.memberof.count -gt 1}|Select-Object Name

I was actually looking for something similar to your second example as well, so thx again :)

Comment: @Atle if the answer helped you out consider marking it as the answer similarly if you found it helpful please upvote as well.